# Can I pass a variable to a Google query's where condition?

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I think this is a simple question, but need help as I am new...so please go easy on me =)

I want to use a variable in the WHERE clause of my query using the Google Visualization API Query Language.

I have a variable called studentId that the user can set using a textbox on the page, and would like to run this query `query.setQuery('SELECT B WHERE B = studentId COUNT(B)');` but this query is only checking cells where the actual contents of the cell is "studentId".

Can I pass a variable's value to the where clause of this query?  How?

I feel that there should be a simple answer to this but am coming up blank after much searching.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a variable in the query.  If `studentId` is a number, use this:

```
query.setQuery('SELECT B WHERE B = ' + studentId + ' COUNT(B)');
```

if it is a string, use this:

```
query.setQuery('SELECT B WHERE B = "' + studentId + '" COUNT(B)');
```